# Why isn't Windows' game controller properties able to recognize the guide button on the F310?

Tags: controllers, windows-7

[image]

It seems to work on Steam Big Picture but somehow it won't get detected in both Xpadder and Windows' built in [game controller properties thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc7af.png). It doesn't even show up on the buttons list there.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Home' button on xinput controllers is a dedicated key which cannot be used as anything other than 'Home' button. It's not detected, because it's not considered a regular button.

Comment: So is this a limitation on Windows itself? Because Steam can use it.

Comment: It's a limitation on how the button works. It's not registered as a controller button, as it is a 'Home' button. Certain applications will detect the 'Home' button, but it can never be remapped, because it's *special* controller button with an exclusive function.